# SIMD extensions support in Emscripten?

Tags: simd, emscripten

I'm trying to use `_mm_comieq_ss` in a project that compiles using Emscripten (currently using 1.21.0 at the time of writing this), but it seems like the function is not available. I see that Emscripten provides emmintrin.h/xmmintrin.h and it *looks* quite complete, however some functions are missing (such as `_mm_comieq_ss`) so I am wondering what are my options here?

Should I use a different function, or is the Emscripten support for SIMD extensions not usable yet?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use SIMD extensions with Emscripten?

Comment: I have to port a library through Emscripten that wasn't written by me, that make use of SIMD extensions.

Comment: You may try SIMD headers from clang distribution. Unlike `gcc`, `clang` headers are mostly implemented with portable SIMD notation.

Answer (score 2):

See [the emscripten docs on "Porting SIMD code targetting webassembly"](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/simd.html). At the time of this writing, `_mm_comieq_ss` is *scalarized* (uses of it will be converted into non-SIMD instructions).

If you're interested in why some instructions on that page are supported and some aren't, it explains that what Emscripten supports is correlated to the [WASM SIMD proposal](https://github.com/webassembly/simd/). For x86 SSE instructions that aren't directly in the proposal, it sometimes emulates them using combinations of other WASM SIMD instructions.

Inlining a comment by [@PeterCordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132):

> Ironically, [`_mm_comieq_ss`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=comieq&ig_expand=1369) already is a scalar operation, reading the low float of two vectors, and producing integer FLAGS. (The [`comiss`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss) instruction, the same instruction a compiler would use for comparing two scalar float like for if (x == y)). Unlike cmpss, which produces a 0 or -1 (all-bits set) result in the low element of an XMM vector reg, leaving the others unchanged.